# Show an executed script result in a html div tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a button in a simple html file that onClick calls to the next script:

```
function onShowTest() {
    $('div#content').html('<script>alert("Hello")</script>');
};
```

so basically when I click the button I just get an alert.

What I would actually like to achieve is that in the div tag (`content`) I will see a result of a script which draws something (not just an alert like in the example which has nothing to do with the result being shown in the div tag).

Also, the function is located in some other file named **utils.js.**

I tried using `jQuery.getScript()` but I just can't get it work.

Comment: A script that executes has no return value, it just has side-effects. So in your snippet you are passing `undefined` into the `html()` function, no matter what the script tag contains.

Comment: @user550413 are you just trying to inject some content into the DIV, using a function defined in utils.js?

Comment: Okay, but how can I achieve what I described (even in some other way)?

Comment: Assuming your function returns something (some kind of HTML) what's stopping you from simply calling your function and returning its value into the HTML?

Comment: @user550413 $('div#content').html(utils.getContentToInject()); ??

Comment: @Xaxis I have a menu in the left side with many options. Different options show different results in the same DIV area.

Answer (score 3):

To generate HTML in place, you need to use something like `document.write`, but that only works at parse time. Once the HTML document is finished, calling it will start a new document and blow away the existing content.

If you want to generate HTML somewhere, then you need to use DOM manipulation to do it, and you can't do it based on where the script element appears.

If you want to *draw* something then you need to use SVG, Canvas or another API for creating images. SVG is just more DOM manipulation. Canvas would first require DOM manipulation to create a canvas element, and then calling canvas api methods on that element.

If you want the code to do that to come from elsewhere, but get the target from "here", then you should write a *function* to do the manipulation and pass it an argument which tells it where to perform the manipulation.

Comment: Originally I have several jsp files and using ajax I dynamically injected them to the same div tag area. Then I had a jsp file which included a js script which draws a chart but chart part is not shown.